# Print Infrastructure: How many LAN printers is too many?

Tags: networking, local-area-network, latency, network-printer, architecture

I am a new network administrator for a larger company that is planning on moving to a new building. Currently I am working on designing a layout for each office, as well as the warehouse in terms of how everyone's printers and PC's will be hooked up. I have about 15 users who each will have a printer in their office. This printer will be only used by each these users individually, so they do not necessarily need to be network printers.

However, I would like to have it so that we don't need to run a cable directly from the printer to each user's PC. My question is if all of these printers -- that will only be used by one individual user personally -- were connected to the network, how much bandwidth will be eaten up as a result? I am worried that we are wasting resources by connecting these printers to the network when only one individual will be printing to each of them.

Bluetooth printers? WiFi direct? USB cable directly from the printer to each users desktop or docking station? What would be a good solution here?

I'm thinking I know the answer, as since only one person will be using each, there is no need for them to be passing traffic across the network if the distance they should be traveling is 7 feet. Would love to hear another take on it.

Thanks!

-Bren

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if all of these PC's that will only be used by one person were
> connected to the network, how much bandwidth will be eaten up as a
> result?

Probably not enough to even be noticeable unless your users are printing 500MB CAD files every 5 minutes.

If it were me, I'd connect each user to their respective printer with WiFi direct or USB cable and be done with it.